# Wrapper class design and dependency injection

Tags: c++, oop, wrapper

I have a simple FTP class that take care of downloading and uploading through cURL libraries:

```
class FTPClient
{
public:
    explicit FTPClient(const std::string& strIPAddress);
    virtual ~FTPClient();

    bool DownloadFile(const std::string& strRemoteFile, const std::string& strLocalFile);
    bool UploadFile(const std::string& strLocalFile, const std::string& strRemoteFile);

private:
    static size_t WriteToFileCallBack(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream);
    static size_t ReadFromFileCallback(void* ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream);

    std::string m_strUser;
    std::string m_strPass;
    std::string m_strIPAddress;
    std::string m_strPort;

    mutable CURL* m_objCurlSession;
};
```

I've asked some advices on how it could be implemented and structured better since it's the base and core for a project and it's going to be used in many parts. 
I've been told to use a cURLWrapper class to wrap all of the cURL calls (curl_easy_setopt(..)), but then I've been told to create an Interface for the FTP class, a cURLWrapper that just calls the FTP methods and then a concrete class.. but still it's too abstract for me and don't understand the best way to implement it and which path to follow..

How would you approach this small structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a simple interface for your FTP class:

```
class IFTPClient
{
public:
    virtual ~IFTPClient();

    virtual bool DownloadFile(const std::string& strRemoteFile, const std::string& strLocalFile) = 0;
    virtual bool UploadFile(const std::string& strLocalFile, const std::string& strRemoteFile) = 0;
};
```

I assume your static callback methods are calling back into some class instance rather than into a singleton? That's fine then. Derive your class from the interface:

```
class FTPClient:IFTPClient
{
    ...
```

I notice that you have the IP address passed into the constructor and have other parameters (user name, password, port, etc.) defined elsewhere. That does not appear to be quite consistent yet. You would need to refactor that so that these parameters can be set through interface methods or add those to the upload/download methods.

Construct your `FTPClient` object(s) before you need it elsewhere and then only pass ("inject") the interface into objects that want to use the `FTPClient`. For unit testing without the use of the actual `FTPClient`, construct a mock object derived from the same interface and inject that into other objects instead.

Other objects simply make use of the functionality exposed in the interface and don't need to know or worry about its internal implementation; if you decide to use `curl` or something else is then entirely up to `FTPClient`.

That's in in a nutshell; you may want to search for dependency injection and frameworks on the Internet but you don't need a framework to follow dependency injection principles and, in my opinion, they can be overkill for simple projects.